# foreach items in hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

I need to use `Hastable` (Not `List` and not `Dictionary`), and I have many variables with keys. I add keys and variables to class, and use it in my program. But I don't know how to parse `Hashtable`. I tried this:

```
        Hashtable toboofer = null;

        string path = @"my.bin";

        FileStream fin = File.OpenRead(path);

        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            toboofer = (Hashtable)bf.Deserialize(fin);

            for (int i = 0; i <= toboofer.Count; i++ )
                //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in toboofer)
                {
                    myclass cl = new myclass();
                    cl.Fio = toboofer[i].ToString();
                    cl.About = toboofer[i].ToString();
                }
        }
```

but I have an error. When I try `string item` or cycle `for` I have an error too.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You should really consider using strong typed `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of  `Hashtable`.

Comment: So, why are `Dictionary<,>` and `List<>` solutions unacceptable? There may be a way to duck that requirement that helps with this parsing section.

Comment: dictionary and list doesn't desiarilze from binary file. may bee i had mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Hashtable` has `DictionaryEntry` as collection element

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in toboofer)
{
    // do something
}
```

Make list of `myclass` from hashtable:

```
var listOfMyClass = toboofer.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().
                             Select(e => new myclass() 
               { Fio = e.Key.ToString(), About = e.Value.ToString() });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this hashtable make use if DictionaryEntry, where KeyValuePair generic used by generic dictionary .Net 2 (and onwards)

Aslo note that Hashtable doesnt have generic version of it and Each element in hastable represented by DictionaryEntry

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
```